How can I set up a Minikube deployment/service and expose it locally so that the exposed endpoint is available during a rolling update?
How can I set up a Minikube deployment/service and expose it locally so that the exposed endpoint is available during a rolling update?
minikube version: v1.34.0
commit: 210b148df93a80eb872ecbeb7e35281b3c582c61
Docker version 27.3.1, build ce12230
I have set up a Minikube locally on my computer in a Docker Container. There I have a deployment 'spring-boot-k8s' running on one pod. I have created for a service:
kubectl describe svc spring-boot-k8s
Name:                     spring-boot-k8s
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   app=spring-boot-k8s
Annotations:              <none>
Selector:                 app=spring-boot-k8s
Type:                     NodePort
IP Family Policy:         SingleStack
IP Families:              IPv4
IP:                       ***.***.***.*
IPs:                      ***.***.***.*
Port:                     <unset>  8080/TCP
TargetPort:               8080/TCP
NodePort:                 <unset>  32447/TCP
Endpoints:                ***.***.*.*:8080
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>

If I now expose the endpoint of my application with 'minikube service spring-boot-k8s' I get the following output:
minikube service spring-boot-k8s
|-----------|-----------------|-------------|---------------------------|
| NAMESPACE |      NAME       | TARGET PORT |            URL            |
|-----------|-----------------|-------------|---------------------------|
| default   | spring-boot-k8s |        xxxx | http://192.xxx.xx.x:32447 |
|-----------|-----------------|-------------|---------------------------|
* Start Tunnel für den Service spring-boot-k8s
|-----------|-----------------|-------------|-----------------------|
| NAMESPACE |      NAME       | TARGET PORT |          URL          |
|-----------|-----------------|-------------|-----------------------|
| default   | spring-boot-k8s |             | http://127.x.x.x:2152 |
|-----------|-----------------|-------------|-----------------------|

If I now perform a deployment or rolling update with 'kubectl set image deployment/spring-boot-k8s springboot-k8s-demo=springboot-k8s-demo:2.0', I can see that one pod is first starting before the current pod is terminating but the specified link is not accessible for a few seconds, why? I thought a rolling update would not cause any downtime. i would like to measure the availability of the endpoint later to see if there really is a downtime
Edit:
This is my deployment.yaml:
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: spring-boot-k8s
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: spring-boot-k8s
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 1
      maxUnavailable: 0
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: spring-boot-k8s
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: spring-boot-k8s
          image: springboot-k8s-demo:1.0
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080

What do i need to change so that the endpoint will be available through the deployment?

Do you have correct health checks set up to ensure the new Pod is running before the old one is deleted?

do you mean that i have to change my deployment file with kubectl edit deployment spring-boot-k8s?

You should edit the .yaml file that you've checked into source control.  Keeping track of what you've done with kubectl edit can be tricky.

you mean the deployment.yaml from my spring boot project has to be configuerd with the right health setup or a different file?
